# Prove there are no natural solutions for an equation of two unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I have the equation from a problem, for which I now need to show that the equation either has or doesn't have a pair of natural numbers, where $k$ is odd, as a solution:

$$\frac{9}{40}x^2 + \frac{31}{9} = 10^k, for\ k, x \in \mathbb{N} $$

Modified for only odd numbers:

$$\frac{9}{40}x^2 + \frac{31}{9} = 10^{2y+1}, for\ x,y \in \mathbb{N} $$

My one approach was to prove that the left term was not divisible by $10$ but I didn't find a method to do that.

My second approach was to solve for $x$ and work out the kinks in the root to show a natural value for $x$ to be impossible:

$$
x=\sqrt{\frac{360 \cdot 10^{2y+1}- 279}{81}}, for\ x,y \in \mathbb{N} 
$$

(I used the common denominator 360 to make it easier)

E.g. all numbers divisble by $81$ end in $1, 2, 3..$ and the term above has a divisble by $10$ part, from which $279$ is subtracted, meaning it ends in 1. If it ends in $1$, the number under the root must result to, because it is divisble by $81$, $10n + 1$. I can't see how this helps further..

Is there a method to find natural solutions for one equation with two unknowns (or to show there are none)? This method should generally work with any equation with two unknowns that are natural.

Comment: Rewrite as $81x^2+31\cdot 40=10^k \cdot 360$. First summand and the sum are divisible by $9$, second summand is not.

Comment: Ah yeah. I'll edit the question to clarify, but im also interested in a general approach to such a problem.

Comment: wait how would that work? it should be $81x^2 + 279 = 10^k * 360$ or $81x^2 + 31 * 40 = 10^k$. The $360$ is exclusive to the first term

Comment: You're multiplying every term by $360$, such that the equality remains an equality. Hence $(9/40) \times 360 = 81, (31/9) \times 360 = 1240$, and the RHS must be $360 \times 10^k$

Comment: FYI - `$P(x)\text{ for }x\in \Bbb N$` gives "$P(x)\text{ for }x\in \Bbb N$", and `$P(x), \forall x\in \Bbb N$` gives "$P(x), \forall x\in \Bbb N$".